# Feel like throwing up / fainting during new exercise routine

Tags: workout, health, injury-prevention, pain, heart-rate

6'1, 84kg, 25 year old, male, resting heart rate 90, during this routine gets up to 167, as measured with Garmin Forerunner with heart rate sensor attachment strap.

New exercise routine is 3 sets of 15 chin-ups (alt. day pull-ups) superset with 3 sets of 16 jump lunges, followed by superset of 45kg barbell (3x 8) squat and (3x 8) standing barbell shoulder press.

*Haven't gotten to the next part of my routine yet, so won't mention it.*

Heart rate spikes during each exercise and then near the end I start to feel really sick and lean against some equipment then leave (my routine unfinished). I did faint after going too hard on single legged dumbbell squats 6 months ago, so have avoided them since.

I've only attempted this new routine twice, and I got further into it this time (barely got the first set of squats last time, this time I did all but last superset of squat+press).

**Is this normal, and I should just man up, should I run more to get fit before getting into this, or is this something I should get checked by a medical doctor?**

Comment: I have a resting HR of 55-60 so I guess 90 is not that normal.And I am the same age,height and weight as you.

Comment: With RHR 90, you should not run. You should walk. A lot. That should be your priority.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT NORMAL**.  Stop what you are doing.  You should not have to feel this way when you exercise, no matter what you are told by personal trainers or coaches.

What you are describing--exercise induced syncope and nausea, and the heart rate you are reporting, is not safe.  You do not mention your age range, but I suspect your HR is too high.

Even if you do not suffer physiological damage from such circumstances, just the possibility of a partial loss of consciousness is an immediate threat to your safety during a workout.  You could lose muscle control; you could fall or have an object fall on you.  This is completely unacceptable.  The internet is littered with "workout fail" videos depicting people passing out while squatting.  It may look funny but it is seriously dangerous, even with a squat cage.

The heart rate is a sign that there's too much exertion going on:  your heart is trying to pump more oxygenated blood to your tissues to keep up with the rate of energy expenditure.  The syncope and nausea are a sign of insufficient oxygenation to your brain.

Bottom line:  you aren't taking enough rest between sets and between exercises, for your own body.  Everyone is different.  What works for someone else may not work for you.  You may well have an underlying health condition, and I am not a doctor, so I can only recommend that you see a physician.

Comment: Thanks, I'll seek out a medical doctor. PS: I'm 25 years old.